# Mapbox drive and lane level maps

Tags: openstreetmap, mapbox

I am looking for a source of maps that identifies lane-level streets (i.e. maps that encode all lanes of a street). Mapbox has recently released [Mapbox Drive](https://www.mapbox.com/drive/), but I could not figure out how to access these maps. I hope if anyone could assist on finding how to get access to these maps.
Also, are there other resources that I can utilize to get lane-level details? I am aware that OpenStreetMaps encodes the number of lanes of a street, but does not have polylines for these lines.

Comment: Do you really need polylines for individual lanes?

Comment: I believe yes, as this will be used for navigation.

Comment: What for? OSM has polylines for roads and keys for [lanes](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key:lanes) and [turn:lanes](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key:turn#Turning_indications_per_lane). This is sufficient for OSM-based routers to provide clear instructions which lanes to use while navigating. OsmAnd is a very good example for this.

Comment: You are probably right, however, our application requires to know (with the help of a GPS) at which lane i am located.

Answer (score 1):

No, you don't need lane-level details for navigation. Two decades of navigation software prove that.

If you read properly, Mapbox seems to derive "lane-level" detail automatically from "sensor data", so I guess this at least means using some source of (global?) car GPS travel data, next to possibly and undoubtedly very limitedly available 3D lidar road or photogrammetric scans.

So I doubt their source lane-level data is openly available, and certainly OpenStreetMap doesn't yet have lane-level detail on a global scale.

So your way to access this is ("but I could not figure out how to access these maps") is to get a payed subscription for their SDK...